# What are extensions, add-ons and plugins?

Tags: browser-addons, plugins

For example, Firefox has three sections for modifying the application:

- Add-ons
- Extensions
- Plugins

They all seem to do the same thing: provide some extra functionality or disable existing functionality.

What are the main differences between them? How do you know that "what" you have is an *add-on*, an *extension* or a *plugin*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions and Plugins are different types of Add-on

Extensions add functionality to Firefox

Plugins allow Firefox to access additional media on the web (i.e. MP3 via QuickTime, SWF via Flash or PDF via Adobe Reader)

**EDIT Further explanation following comment**

There are actually three kinds of Add-on.

If you go to `Tools` -> `Add-ons` you will have 4 tabs including `Extensions` and `Plugins`, along with `Themes` and `Get Add-ons`.

Plugins are generally installed by other applications you have installed on your computer.

Extensions are generally installed in Firefox by the user.

Comment: Bu ... if plugins and extensions are add-ons and FF provides a third option for add-ons, what are add-ons?

Comment: @Tom: FF provides an option to "get add-ons", which means, you can get both extensions and plugins via the same link. So Shevek's definition of add-ons is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think this page sums it up. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Customizing+Firefox+with+add-ons